# Elements bigger on iPhone landscape VS portrait?

Tags: ios, iphone, responsive

I'm working with media queries for iPhone. I noticed that when I flip my phone from PORTRAIT to LANDSCAPE, everything gets bigger.

For example, the NAV is taller on PORTRAIT. What's really weird, though, is the Inspector says it's the same height for both orientations: 90px.

What the hell is going on?

How can an element that has the same height be bigger on different orientations?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have autolayout setup?

Comment: Not sure what that is?

Comment: You should probably tag this as web FYI, everyone here thinks you're developing native iOS.

Comment: If the inspector says it's 90px, it probably is. You're probably noticing a difference because of how the iPhone scales at different screen sizes since the internal software measures in points rather than pixels. You should post some useable example code so we can see what you are referring to.